# How do i reverse and break an Array to form a new maximized Array?

Tags: java, arraylist, logic

**Question details :** This certain coding problem wanted me to do this :

- Accept a few numbers in an array and then perform the following operations on  itself(say the array is A) to form a new Array X such that it's elements are maximized(example below).

These operations are to be performed until array A is empty, and at a time we can choose to do only one of the below operations.

- 1: remove the last number of array A and add it to the array X
- 2: remove the last 2 numbers of array A and add their product to the array X
- 3: reverse the array A and remove the last element and add it to array X
- 4: reverse the array A and add the product of last 2 elements to array X, and also remove those 2 elements from array A too.

For example if set A = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5] then set X = [15, 1, 8] following the operations [2, 3, 2] which sums to 24, which is the maximum sum possible from every possible combination of operations to create set X from set A.

[Question source](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/2-dimensional/practice-problems/algorithm/maximise-xor-f240c1e1/)

**My problem :** I did code for this, but it only works out for some test cases and mostly it doesn't for other inputs, in the sense it outputs wrong answers but, i fail to notice where does my logic err, so please point out my mistake/modify my code.

**My approach :** First i did each of the 4 operations(except the removing or reversing part) and picked that operation which produced the largest element and thus went on to perform that full operation(removing or reversing set A and forming set X) so, that set X can be maximized. I went on doing this till set A was emptied.

my essential code snippets below :

```
public class Firstly {
 public static ArrayList A = new ArrayList();//declared set A
  public static ArrayList X = new ArrayList();//declared set X

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int s=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int u=sc.nextInt();//accepted the size of set A from the user
  for(int i=0;i<u;i++)
      A.add(sc.nextInt());//accepted 'u' numbers in set A from the user

/*below i define and use a method 'execute' which performs one of 
 the 4 operations on set A as well as makes set X */

while(!A.isEmpty())//'execute' is implemented until set A is emptied
      execute(maxi(A),X,A);

for (Iterator it = X.iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
    s+=  (int) it.next();//adding all the set X elements
System.out.println(s);
}

/*maxi method below returns the number that is the largest possible among 
  the 4 operations that can be performed on set A*/ 


private static int maxi(ArrayList A) {
      ArrayList Y = new ArrayList();//declared a set Y

      Y.add(A.get(A.size()-1));//adds the product of 1st operation

      if(A.size()>1){//adds the product of 2nd operation
      int k= (int) A.get(A.size()-1);
      int h= (int) A.get(A.size()-2);
          Y.add(k*h);
      }

  Y.add(A.get(0));//adds the product of 3rd operation

      if(A.size()>1){//adds the product of 4th operation
        int kt= (int) A.get(0);
      int ht=(int) A.get(1);
      Y.add(kt*ht);
      }
      return Y.indexOf(Collections.max(Y));/*returns the index of the 
    largest of the 4 elements*/
}

 /*depending on the value(index) the 'maxi' method returns, 'execute' 
  method performs the requisite operation on set A as well as on set X*/


private static void execute(int maxi, ArrayList X, ArrayList A){
    switch(maxi){
        case 0://if the largest number is produced by 1st operation
            X.add(A.remove(A.size()-1));
            break;
        case 1://if the largest number is produced by 2nd operation
           int k= (int) A.remove(A.size()-1);
      int h=(int) A.remove(A.size()-1);
      X.add(h*k);
      break;
        case 2://if the largest number is produced by 3rd operation
            X.add(A.remove(0));
             Collections.reverse(A);
             break;
        default ://if the largest number is produced by 4th operation
              int kt=(int) A.remove(0);
      int ht=(int) A.remove(0);
            X.add(ht*kt);
             Collections.reverse(A);                
    }
  }  
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Hi there, did you solve your problem? Is there something I could had missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, your example is not.

For example if set A = [1, 4, 2, 3, 5] then set X = [15, 1, 8] following the operations [2, 3, 2] which sums to 24, which is the maximum sum possible from every possible combination of operations to create set X from set A.

```
Array A: 1 4 2 3 5  
Op: 2 
Array X: 15  
Array A: 1 4 2  
Op: 2 
Array X: 15 8  
Array A: 1  
Op: 1 
Array X: 15 8 1  
Array A:  
Result:24
```

> Your problem is on the second step: [1 4 2] why would you pick the op
>   1? if the op 2 is higher on the result value. If this is not the idea
>   then you have to change your "maxi" function to pick the op that you
>   want.

Another Example:

For this entrance: 8 8 1 4 1 2 0 9

I get this correct and expected results: 64 9 4 2 0

With this operation order: 4 3 4 2 1

```
Array A: 8 8 1 4 1 2 0 9  
Op: 4 
Array X: 64  
Array A: 9 0 2 1 4 1  
Op: 3 
Array X: 64 9  
Array A: 1 4 1 2 0  
Op: 4 
Array X: 64 9 4  
Array A: 0 2 1  
Op: 2 
Array X: 64 9 4 2  
Array A: 0  
Op: 1 
Array X: 64 9 4 2 0  
Array A:  
Result:79
```

My test code: I change some things to adapt to the correct enviroment. **USE JDK1.8**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Firstly {

    private static void printArrayA(List<Integer> A){
        // PRINT THE ARRAY
        A.forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
        System.out.println(" ");
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> A = new LinkedList<Integer>();// declared set A
        List<Integer> X = new LinkedList<Integer>();// declared set X

        int s = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int u = sc.nextInt();// accepted the size of set A from the user
        for (int i = 0; i < u; i++)
            A.add(sc.nextInt());// accepted 'u' numbers in set A from the user

        System.out.print("Array A: ");
        printArrayA(A);

        /*
         * below i define and use a method 'execute' which performs one of the 4
         * operations on set A as well as makes set X
         */

        while (!A.isEmpty())
            // 'execute' is implemented until set A is emptied
            execute(maxi(A), X, A);

        for (Iterator it = X.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
            s += (Integer) it.next();// adding all the set X elements
        System.out.println("Result:" + s);
    }

    /*
     * maxi method below returns the number that is the largest possible among the 4
     * operations that can be performed on set A
     */

    private static int maxi(List<Integer> A) {
        List<Integer> Y = new LinkedList<Integer>();// declared a set Y

        Y.add(A.get(A.size() - 1));// adds the product of 1st operation

        if (A.size() > 1) {// adds the product of 2nd operation
            int k = (Integer) A.get(A.size() - 1);
            int h = (Integer) A.get(A.size() - 2);
            Y.add(k * h);
        }

        Y.add(A.get(0));// adds the product of 3rd operation

        if (A.size() > 1) {// adds the product of 4th operation
            int kt = (Integer) A.get(0);
            int ht = (Integer) A.get(1);
            Y.add(kt * ht);
        }
        int index = Y.indexOf(Collections.max(Y))+1;
        System.out.print("Op: "+index);
        return Y.indexOf(Collections.max(Y));/*
                                                 * returns the index of the largest of the 4 elements
                                                 */
    }

    /*
     * depending on the value(index) the 'maxi' method returns, 'execute' method
     * performs the requisite operation on set A as well as on set X
     */

    private static void execute(int maxi, List<Integer> X, List<Integer> A) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        switch (maxi) {
        case 0:// if the largest number is produced by 1st operation
            X.add(A.remove(A.size() - 1));
            break;
        case 1:// if the largest number is produced by 2nd operation
            int k = (Integer) A.remove(A.size() - 1);
            int h = (Integer) A.remove(A.size() - 1);
            X.add(h * k);
            break;
        case 2:// if the largest number is produced by 3rd operation
            X.add(A.remove(0));
            Collections.reverse(A);
            break;
        default:// if the largest number is produced by 4th operation
            int kt = (Integer) A.remove(0);
            int ht = (Integer) A.remove(0);
            X.add(ht * kt);
            Collections.reverse(A);
        }
        System.out.print("Array X: ");
        printArrayA(X);
        System.out.print("Array A: ");
        printArrayA(A);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps :)